# Loading bar in div before showing

Tags: jquery, hide, show, fade

I have the following Jquery which, on clicking on a Checkbox, re-loads a DIV passing the value of the box and showing new items based on a query.

I would like to have a "Loading" bar for 3 seconds or so... before loading the content of the DIV, fading out after. And then load the DIV with a fade-in effect. I tried a few things but did't work.

Here is my code.

Thanks!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $(".loadingItems").delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            var color = [];
            color.push($(this).val());
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color);
        }
        else if ($(this).not(':checked')) 
        {
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally considered bad practice to have your users wait for three seconds just so you can show off your loading bar, and by the time it's faded out, six seconds have passed and your users have left. Remove the loading bar after the ajax call is finished and the content is ready. Also, are you sure you should be using an array in a querystring ?

```
$(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").on('change', function() {
        $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
        if (this.checked) {
            var color = [];
            color.push(this.value); //array in querystring ?
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color, function() {
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
            });
        }else{
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php', function() {
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);  //remove when load is complete
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'll take a wild guess and say this is what you're after :

```
$(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").on('change', function() {
        $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300); //fade in on change
        var qs = this.checked ? 'color='+this.value : '';
        $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php'+qs, function() {
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300); //remove when load is complete
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: @adeneo - thanks a lot, I need to test this but looks like a great option. The reason why I had an array is because I wanted to allow multiple checked boxes... but it never worked :(

Comment: Did you open your console (F12 in chrome) to find out what the problem was ?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? ... nothing else

Comment: That means you have a typo in your code, usually a period, parenthesis or something else in the wrong place. In the chrome inspector you click the error to see where it is. I copied both code examples above into [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kypeh/) and they are working just fine, there seems to be no typos in the code above ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple `setTimeout()` function can delay the execution of a command.

```
$("#loader").fadeIn();
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#loader").fadeOut();  
  $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color);
  ...
},3000);
```

The delay is specified as the second parameter in the `setTimeout` function.  In this example I have placed `3000`.  This number is in milliseconds; 1 second = 1000 milliseconds.

Reference -

- [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a jQuery preloader?

http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback function of [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method:

> .fadeOut( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
>   `callback`: A function to call once the animation is complete.

```
var color = [];
color.push($(this).val());
$(".loadingItems").delay(2700).fadeOut(300, function(){
    $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?color='+color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple function that you can use whenever you are loading something into a div

```
function loadIntoDiv(div,url){
    $("#loader").fadeIn();
    $(div).load(url,function(){
        $("#loader").fadeOut();
    });
}
```

example: `loadIntoDiv(".indexMain",'indexMain.php');`